# AADSTS501051: Application '{API GUID}'(DEV-API) is not assigned to a role for the application '{API GUID}'(DEV-API)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-api-apps

I want to access one API by its Client Credential directly not via any web application

```
private async Task<string> GetAutheticationToken(string APITypeSelected, string APIKeySelected=null)
    {
        string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADTenant"];
        string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[APIKeySelected];
        string apiID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[APITypeSelected];
        //appKey = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(appKey);
        string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
            ClientCredential clientCredential = null;
            authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(authority);
            //encodeURIComponent(client_secret);
            clientCredential = new ClientCredential(apiID, appKey);
            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiID, clientCredential);

            return authResult.AccessToken;
        }
    }
```

while executing I am getting bellow error(AADSTS501051) in this line

```
authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiID, clientCredential);
```

> AADSTS501051: Application '{API GUID}'(DEV-API) is not assigned to a
>   role for the application '{API GUID}'(DEV-API).

Do I have to give API permission to itself.

What I need to do.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This error message indicates that you need to add an "App role" to your app registration. You can do so by first adding a new App role on *{API GUID}*

[image]

and then assign the app *{API GUID}* this role (don't forget to give admin consent)

[image]

Essentially what is happening here is that your app registration *{API GUID}* got a role on *{API GUID}* to create access tokens for the audience *{API GUID}*, so: itself.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make a user role for application if app assignment is required. if not there is no problem. If app assignment is required, Go back to api permission and in my api give permission for the created role, see Microsoft documentation url

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration

Answer (score 0):

Ahh so you want an access token to the API itself? Not sure if that's possible..

If this in another app, it should be registered as another app in Azure AD. 
It can then require application permissions on the API and call it via client credentials. 
You can see how to define permissions here: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

If this is within the same app, it sounds odd that it would acquire a token for itself.

Comment: Please tell me how to consume the API.I am already authenticated in the application. I want to consume the API directly not via any other application. that's what the requirement is.

Comment: Can't you call the service layer that the API calls directly?

Comment: I need to consume the API..that's the expectation. Do I need to change in Manifest.

Answer (score -1):

When you use "authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiID, clientCredential);" to get the access token, you need to use identifierUri of your ad application as resource.

[image]

For example:

```
string tenantId = "your tenant id or name, for example: hanxia.onmicrosoft.com";
            string clientId = "your client id"; 
            string resource = "the identifierUri of your ad application ";
            string clientSecret = "";

        ClientCredentia clientCredentia = new ClientCredentia(clientId,clientSecret);

                var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId);
                AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredentia);
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest).

Comment: AADSTS501051: Application '{API GUID}'(DEV-API) is not assigned to a role for the application '{API GUID}'(DEV-API).

Comment: I think it needs some configuration change in azure API.

Comment: Is that you protect  the api by the same application?